# Why has this gsettings command stopped working between 16.04 and 16.04.1?

Tags: gsettings

I was using this snippet of code (shell script) to interact with the Gnome Terminal profile on 16.04 and it worked fine

```
profile=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default)
profile=${profile:1:-1} # remove leading and trailing single quotes
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${profile}/ \
background-transparency-percent
```

I then updated the system by installing 16.04.1 now when I run the above commands, either by a script or by on a command-line `gsettings` just returns its "usage" message:

> $ gsettings get
>   org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${profile}/
>   Usage:   gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] get SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY ...

What do I need to do to get this command working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted the key name, like `background-transparency-percent`:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${profile}/ background-transparency-percent
```

Comment: ah thanks, interestingly, I did try the command with the `background-transparency-percent key (you can see in the first section of code I pasted).  Your answer prompted me to try it again though,  and it solved the issue, however I think what possibly happened was that the line continuation "\" char may have had spaces and not a "\n" after it, maybe causing the key to be ignored by the shell?